# PostgreSQL default authentication method

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

Both [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) and [Digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04) agree that, upon installation, Postgres is set up to use `ident` authentication, "meaning that it associates Postgres roles with a matching Unix/Linux system account. If a role exists within Postgres, a Unix/Linux username with the same name is able to sign in as that role."

However, in the default client authentication configuration file, authentication is set to `peer` or `md5`:

```
$ sudo less /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
...
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I use PostgreSQL as development database for Ruby on Rails and it works fine. What authentication method I am using considering that I never edited `pg_hba.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostgreSQL doc says about `ident` in its [list of auth methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html):

> **Ident authentication**, which relies on an “Identification Protocol”
>   (RFC 1413) service on the client's machine. (On local Unix-socket
>   connections, **this is treated as peer authentication**.)

A rule like this in `pg_hba.conf`

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

means that if the connection comes from a Unix domain socket (TYPE column=local), and whatever is the database (database column=all), and if the user is `postgres`, then the authentication scheme to use is `peer`.

If `ident` was there instead of `peer`, **that would not make any difference** as per the comment above saying that they mean the same for local connections.

The other rules that point to `peer` in the `pg_hba.conf` from the question  have `local` in the leftmost column, so it applies to them as well.

TCP connections to localhost (`127.0.0.1` or `::1`) are not refered to in the `pg_hba.conf` as `local`, this value meaning exclusively Unix domain sockets. This is sometimes confusing because people often refer to TCP connections through localhost (127.0.0.1) as local connections too.

They are often configured by default to use a password, like this:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using password authentication currently and you have chosen md5 algorithm for encryption and here is the procedure to reset your password

**Switch to the PostgreSQL User**

switch to the default PostgreSQL user, postgres:

```
su - postgres
```

then attempt a connection to PostgreSQL:

```
psql
```

the correct, valid response will be similar to:

```
psql (9.3.9)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

**Add/Change the Password for the PostgreSQL User**

Use the following command to change the password for your current user, which should be postgres:

```
\password
```

Enter your new password, and confirm it:

```
Enter new password:
Enter it again:
```

Now quit the psql interface:

```
\q
```

**Edit the Authentication Method**

Edit the configuration file:

```
vim /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Find:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all              all             127.0.0.1/32             ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all              all             ::1/128                  ident
```

Change each ident to md5:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all              all             127.0.0.1/32             md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all              all             ::1/128                  md5
```

Then exit and save the file with the command :wq.

Now restart PostgreSQL:

```
systemctl restart postgresql-9.3
```

**Verify Your Access**

Switch back to the postgres user:

```
su - postgres
```

Enter the PostgreSQL command line:

```
psql
```

You should be prompted with the following (or similar):

```
Password:
psql (9.3.9)
Type "help" for help.
```

Enter your password, and you’re in!

For reference:
        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-methods.html